# Mimes Type not working for zip

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mime-types, assets

In my Symfony application, I want to set only  zip and rar file as  the mime type during the file upload but it's not working  i tried this code

```
    /* * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "1024k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"application/zip,application/octet-stream
    * application/rar,application/octet-stream"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "dossier sur form zip"
     * )
    */
      public $file;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;
```

Comment: Whats not working? How is it failing? Are you trying to restrict user uploads based on mime type or are you trying to upload to a server and set the mime type?

Comment: i m trying to restrict user to upload only zip or rar file but it's not working for me the user can uplaod all kinda of file